# Path connected subsets of disjoint union

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a path connected topological space and consider a continuous map $f: \partial D^2 \rightarrow X$. Take the equivalence relation $\sim_f$ generated by $d \sim f(d)$ for $d \in \partial D^2$ and create the adjunction space $Y=X\sqcup D^2/ \sim_f=X\cup_fD^2$.

Denote by $\pi: X\sqcup D^2 \rightarrow Y $ the quotient map, by $A$ the set $A\subseteq Y$, $A=\pi(\{y \in X\sqcup D^2 | y \in X $ or $y \in D^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\})$, and by $B$ the set $B\subseteq Y$, $B=\pi(D^2\setminus \partial D^2)$.

By the properties of the adjunction spaces $B$ is open, and as an image of a path connected space it is path connected as well.

> Why is are $A,A\cap B$ path connected? Why is $A$ open?

- $A$ is path connected. If I could show that $A$ is homeomorphic to $X\cup_fD\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ then $A$ would be homeomorphic to a a disjoint union of path connected spaces along a non empty set, therefore a path connected space. Hence $A$ would be path connected, but I'm not sure on how to exhibit the homeomorphism.
- $A\cap B$ is path connected. $A\cap B=\pi(D^2\setminus(\{(0,0)\}\cup \partial D^2) )$, since $X$ is disjoint from $D^2$ in the disjoint union. Therefore it is the image of a path connected space, hence path connected.
- $A$ is open. I'm not sure on how to proceed. Maybe knowing that $\pi$ is open or closed could help.

Do you have any hint?

Comment: All of this seems correct to me, and to prove that $A$ is open, what is $\pi^{-1}(A)$? Is it open or not? How do we define the topology on $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't entirely clear, you should imagine gluing the disk along the map specified by $f$.

> A is path connected. If I could show that $A$ is homeomorphic to $X\cup_fD\setminus \{(0,0)\}$...

You're making this too complicated. If you have two points, both of which are in $X$, we're done (because $X$ is path connected). Similarly, if they're both in $D\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, we're also done. If one is in $X$ and the other is in $D\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, drive to the boundary of $D\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ (which is also in $X$ by the identifications), then drive to the point in $X$ via path connectedness.

> $A \cap B$ is path connected...

Looks good to me.

> $A$ is open.

Choose a point $a \in A$. If $a \in D\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, it's easy to see that there is some open $U \ni a$ so that $a \in U \subseteq A$. If the point is not in $D\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, choose $U$ to be all of $X$, along with a small open strip around the boundary of $D$. By quotient topology shenanigans, $U$ is open, and we have $a \in U \subseteq A$.

Then, for all $a \in A$, there is some open $U$ so that $a \in U \subseteq A$, meaning $A$ is open.

---

Assuming you're using this for fundamental group calculations....

The way you want to think about this result is that whenever you "glue a disk" to a space you already know, you are effectively killing the homotopy type of the attaching map, as you can homotope the loop across the disk to make it null-homotopic. This fact is very convenient for calculating the fundamental group if you know the CW structure.